# How to pass state and props from app.js to other files?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner, I just started learning react few days back.
i want to create 2 pages that is friendlist which displays friend list in table form which has all the fields and each field has an edit button.Clicking edit button should go to edit page. where user should be able to edit details.
Can any one please help me to do these 2 pages.

Comment: What you need is redux to have a common store to have your friends information that can then be retrieved and displaed in freindList component and edited from the edit component

Comment: can u please tell me how to do that. Because i am not getting how to do it...i Am not understanding hot to pass states and props.

Comment: As I said you need to make use of redux, its too big to answer here see this redux guide https://scotch.io/bar-talk/getting-started-with-redux-an-intro. If you still need any help in setting that up, I can help

Comment: i am not getting anything how to access those states in friendlist page and edit page. Would u please help me!

Comment: Ok Paras, I will try to work on it today, it will take some time. Hope you can wait

Comment: Ya. Thanks @Shubham.

Comment: Hi @ShubhamKhatri did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In App.js, pass data as prop

```
render() {
   return <Route data={this.state.data}/>
 }
```

Then in Route.js you can get all props and pass it to components

```
const Router = (props) => (
  <HashRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <list data={props.data}/>}/>
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of React-redux to share your application data and change the Route to get a parameter to show a specific friend on Edit page

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import reducers from './reducers'
import FriendList from './containers/FriendList'
import EditFriend from './containers/EditFriend'
const store = createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={FriendList}/>
                <Route path="/edit/:friendId" component={EditFriend}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('container')
)
```

FriendList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class FriendList extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

   };

   render() {
      console.log(this.props.friendsInfo.data);
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Phone No.</td>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>Work</td>
                            <td>City</td>
                            <td>Edit</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.props.friendsInfo && this.props.friendsInfo.data.map((data) => {
                        console.log(data)
                        return(
                            <tr key={data.key}>
                                <td>{data.name}</td>
                                <td>{data.phone}</td>
                                <td>{data.email}</td>
                                <td>{data.work}</td>
                                <td>{data.city}</td>
                                <td><Link to={`/edit/${data.key}`}>Edit</Link></td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })} 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
     }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        friendsInfo: state.FriendList
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FriendList);
```

FriendListReducer

```
const initialState =  {
    data: [ {
      key:1,
      name: "Steve",
      phone: "03974645875",
      email: "st@gmail.com",
      work:"Engg",
      city:"NY"
    }
    ,{
      key:2,
      name: "Stella",
      phone: "04424645875",
      email: "stella@gmail.com",
      work:"Architect",
      city:"NY"
    },{
      key:3,
      name: "Leo",
      phone: "68546855875",
      email: "leo@outlook.com",
      work:"Engg",
      city:"NY"
    },{
      key:4,
      name: "RK",
      phone: "67544645875",
      email: "rkgmail.com",
      work:"Engg",
      city:"NY"
    }]
}

const FriendList = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action) {
        case "EDIT_FRIEND_DATA": 
            return state
        default: 
            return state
    }
}

export default FriendList;
```

EditFriend.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';
class EditFriend extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>Hello {this.props.match.params.friendId}</div>
        )
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        friendsInfo: state.FriendList
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        editFriend: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditFriend);
```

Read the following blog to get started with redux guide: [scotch.io/bar-talk/getting-started-with-redux-an-intro](http://scotch.io/bar-talk/getting-started-with-redux-an-intro)

Visit [Github](https://github.com/mayankshubham/ReactReduxApp) for a complete working code

Comment: I hope this will help you and will be a good start for all that you need, You need to render your EditFriend page based on the key by searching in this.props.friendsInfo and then getting the correct object and rendering it